# How to get the compasison difference Column values between two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

status_tb

```
+----+----------+-------------+----------+
| id | status   | description | state_id |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |     new  | north       | 1        |
|  2 |   assign | south       | 2        |
|  3 |Postponed | east        | 2        |
|  4 |    Fixed | west        | 3        |
|  8 | Verified | north-east  | 1        |
|  9 |   Closed | south-west  | 2        |
| 35 |     Test | South-test  | 4        |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+
```

status_backup_tb

```
+----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+
|backup_id | id | status   | description | state_id |
+----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+
|  1       |  1 |new       | north       | 1        |
|  2       |  2 |assign    | south       | 2        |
|  3       |  3 |Postponed | east        | 2        |
|  4       |  4 | Fixed    | west        | 3        |
|  5       |  8 | Verified | north-east  | 1        |
|  6       |  9 | Closed   | south-west  | 2        |
|  7       |  35| Rejected | Testing     | 4        |
+----------+----+----------+-------------+----------+
```

**Wanted result:** Column_changed only, old_value and new_value

```
 |new_id | id |Column_changed| Old_value   |New_value |
 +-------+----+--------------+-------------+----------+
 |1      | 35 | status       | Test        | Rejected |
 |2      | 35 |description   | South-test  | Testing  |  
 +-------+----+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

If `state_id` and `status` was the one who changed, I wanted to get `id, status and state_id` column and their old_values and new_values instead.

Already try using that but didnt work

```
SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
FROM
(
 SELECT 'Table A' as TableName, A.ID, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, ...
 FROM A
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Table B' as TableName, B.ID, B.COL1, B.COl2, B.COL3, ...
 FROM B
 ) tmp
GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: changes in `state_id` column (if any) also needs to be reported ?

Comment: IF there a change in `state_id` column, it also has to be reported, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to get all changes for respective fields in individual `Select` queries. Eventually `Union` the results of these multiple queries.

We `JOIN` between the two tables using `id` and the condition that the corresponding column values are not matching.

```
(SELECT 
   s.id, 
   'status' AS Column_changed, 
   s.status AS Old_value, 
   b.status AS New_value 
 FROM status_tb AS s
 JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
   ON b.id = s.id AND 
      b.status <> s.status)

UNION ALL 

(SELECT 
   s.id, 
   'description' AS Column_changed, 
   s.description AS Old_value, 
   b.description AS New_value 
 FROM status_tb AS s
 JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
   ON b.id = s.id AND 
      b.description <> s.description)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
   s.id, 
   'state_id' AS Column_changed, 
   s.state_id AS Old_value, 
   b.state_id AS New_value 
 FROM status_tb AS s
 JOIN status_backup_tb AS b 
   ON b.id = s.id AND 
      b.state_id <> s.state_id)

ORDER BY id
```

Comment: @EmanulaSohn based on your required output, I fear that this might be the only way to do it in SQL. You may rather consider handling such data display related requirements in application code (eg: PHP, C++, Java etc)

Comment: knows how to do it in c# with the mysql, that where im gonna need it... to display the different data in a new audit_status table

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
((select a.id, 'status' as Column_changed, a.status, b.status
From status_tb as a inner join status_backup_tb as b on a.id = b.id
Where a.status <> b.status)
UNION
(select a.id, 'description' as Column_changed, a.description, b.description
From status_tb as a inner join status_backup_tb as b on a.id = b.id
Where a.status <> b.status))
UNION
((select a.id, 'status' as Column_changed, a.status, b.status
From status_tb as a inner join status_backup_tb as b on a.id = b.id
Where a.status_id <> b.status_id)
UNION
(select a.id, 'description' as Column_changed, a.description, b.description
From status_tb as a inner join status_backup_tb as b on a.id = b.id
Where a.status_id <> b.status_id))
```

Comment: why are u repeating status and description twice?

Comment: one row for description and one row for status as `Column_change`.